# Add files to resources and create a resource DLL by code in C#

Tags: c#, dll, resources

Currently, I use a C# class project to generate a resources DLL, by following these steps:

1 - Adding images/files to resources (by drag & drop from Windows explorer to the solution explorer in Visual Studio).

2 - Setting the compilation action to "Resource" for each file (manually).

3 - Starting the project compilation.

4 - Get the dll file that is in the debug / release folder.

I would like to do the same thing programmatically (by giving to the program, the URL of the folder containing the files).
How can I create this DLL? How can I do each of these steps by code?

EDIT : I've tried:

```
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("Library.resources");

DirectoryInfo DirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryUrl);

foreach (FileInfo File in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles())
{ 
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(File.FullName));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(getBytesFromBitmapImage(img));
    writer.AddResource(File.FullName, ms.ToArray());
}
writer.Close();
```

But I don't knwo if it's the right way, and I don't know how to create the DLL after that.

Comment: Yes, its possible to add a resources through code and compile the resources into a dll. What have you tried?

Comment: Look into how to compile a class by hand then reference what is created.